# 2007 Chevy Eqinox

Tags: chevrolet, equinox

In the morning I pull out of my driveway my car will chug and will not go above 25mph. The RPM goes up to just before red line. It will not go anyfaster. Then when it seems to warm up it is ok. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome the the site. GdD's may be on to something in the answer below, but have you had the codes read? I would suggest doing that and updating this post. The details will help us be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: @GinaWhite, by codes that means the On-board diagnostic codes, ie OBD2. Many auto parts stores will do this for free.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site @Gina. This sounds like it could be transmission related, it's not switching gears when it needs to until it has warmed up. That could be due to the fluid being low (more likely being old) or there being a problem with it. I'm not familiar with the Equinox and whether it's possible to check your transmission fluid yourself, I'd suggest checking with your owners manual. If you can check it look at the level and the quality of the fluid. Old fluid will be dark and dirty looking.

Whether or not you can check your fluid a simple test would be to let your car warm up for a few minutes before driving off. If it works normally then this is likely your issue. Note that this is a way to diagnose a problem, it's **not** a fix, you'll need to get the transmission serviced at a reputable shop.